# How can I trigger dropdown while viewing asp.net page

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

There are two Dropdown in the asp.net page. 
When I select first one (city), the second one (district) is triggered.

I have a save button for the page.

When I click the save button, I write the SelectedValues of dropdowns in to the database.
And when I open the page again, I assign the values to the dropdown's selected values.

The first one is ok when I assign `dropdown.SelectedValue` = "5" but the second one is not triggered. How can I trigger it?

Thanx.

Comment: Load the second dropdown in the IsPosback

Comment: show few lines of code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same thing. Suppose you have drop down say ddlCountry and ddlCity. You need to load all cities just for the selected country.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       LoadCountriesInDropDown(ddlCountry);
       ddlCountry.SelectedValue = "5" //For eg:
       LoadCitiesByCountrySelected(ddlCity, ddlCountry.SelectedValue);  // selected country value was set here as 5
       ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
    }
}
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text == "Select")
    {
        ddlCity.Items.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        LoadCitiesByCountrySelected(ddlCity, ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
    }

}
```

Hope this was what you wanted.

Comment: If this is the answer that you were looking for please tick the 'Mark as answer' tick